# ElasticSearch 2.4 date range histogram using the difference between two date fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I haven't been able to find anything regarding this for ES 2.* in regards to the problem here or in the docs, so sorry if this is a duplicate.

What I am trying to do is create an aggregation in an ElasticSearch query that will allow me to create buckets based on the difference in a record between 2 date fields.

I.e. If I had data in ES for a shop, I might like to see the time difference between a purchase_date field and shipped_date field.

So in that instance I'd want to create an aggregate that had buckets to give me the hits for when shipped_date - purchase_date is < 1 day, 1-2 days, 3-4 days or 5+ days.

Ideally I was hoping this was possible in an ES query. Is that the case or would the best approach be to process the results into my own array based on the time difference for each hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using the built in expression language which is enabled by default in ES 2.4. The functionality I wanted was to group my results to show the difference between EndDate and Date Processed in increments of 15 days. Relevant part of the query is:

```
{
   ...,
   "aggs": {
     "reason": {
       "date_histogram": {
       "min_doc_count": 1,
       "interval": "1296000000ms", // 15 days
       "format": "epoch_millis",
       "script": {
         "lang": "expression",
         "inline": "doc['DateProcessed'] > doc['EndDate'] ? doc['DateProcessed'] - doc['EndDate'] : -1"
       }    
     }
     ...
   }
}
```